# why show this erro

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I create a table by [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8rk74r83R8) I just do not use the same list

my code

```py
drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\0')[:-1]
hsa = 0
suphdd =len(drives)
print (drives)
fugas = ["0"]
while suphdd == hsa:
    fugas[hsa] = suko_rata()[hsa] 
    print (fugas[hsa])
    hsa += 1
centlisyt = wx.ListCtrl(panel, (200,20), (100,80), fugas, wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
```

i get this error

```
centlisyt = wx.ListCtrl(panel, (200,20), (100,80), fugas, wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
TypeError: ListCtrl(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 2 has unexpected type 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style):
```

This is the constructor for `wx.ListCtrl` that you're trying to call. Since the two tuples `(200, 20), (100, 80)` look to be `pos` & `size` respectively. I would say you missed the `ID` argument.

I'm not sure what `fugas` is supposed to be though